# How to integrate Alots.in SMS sending in Laravel 8 for OTP?

Tags: laravel-8

I want to integrate otp  sms send to mobile using alots.in in laravel8 i have searched every where but didnot get any guide how to do it.

i have tried from a normal php code how to send sms and used my api details in there place but it didnot send sms.

```
public static function sendSms($mobile,$msg){
    $sender_id = 'GRAPHM';
    $template_id = '1707168414494745591';
    $phone = $mobile;
    $msg = $msg;
    $username = 'rath_admin';
    $apikey = 'EE9AE-0CF92';
    $uri = 'http://www.alots.in/sms-panel/api/http/index.php?';
    $data = array(
    'username'=> $username,
    'apikey'=> $apikey,
    'apirequest'=>'Text',
    'sender'=> $sender_id,
    'route'=>'TRANS',
    'format'=>'JSON',
    'message'=> $msg,
    'mobile'=> $phone,
    'TemplateID' => $template_id,
    );

    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo json_encode(compact('resp', 'error'));

}
```

where is the error in this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.